# I would like to access my Visual Studio Code editor from my Ubuntu 22.04 shell running on windows 11

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-22.04

I cd into the directory I want and type code and get:
$ code
Command 'code' not found, did you mean:
command 'ode' from deb plotutils (2.6-11)
command 'cde' from deb cde (0.1+git9-g551e54d-1.2)
command 'cdde' from deb cdde (0.3.1-1build1)
command 'node' from deb nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3.1)
command 'tcode' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-11ubuntu1)
Try: sudo apt install 
I expected it to open the IDE but it brings errors.What deb name am I supposed to install? When I run code . it brings the same error